# Configuring Oscilloscope timebase from labview

Tags: labview, oscilloscope

I am using Tektronix MSO5034B in one of my project through LabVIEW. In the NI driver for scope to set the timebase "Configure Timebase.vi" is given with 3 controls "Timebase Range", "Position" and "Record Length". There is no straight control to set time/div.

How to find out the values of these 3 parameters from desired time/div? Also, How to find time/div value from these 3 values?

Thanks

Ashutosh[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may have this question, I do have found a way around.

Sampling rate of Scope = Record length / Range

Where range is entire horizontal width of oscilloscope time range which is given below as

Range = Number of divisions * Time/Div

For almost any oscilloscope, number of divisions in horizontal axes are 10.

And time/div is desired value.

For me max sampling rate is 5GS/s and record length is number of samples taken in entire visible window of scope.

hence, Sampling Rate = Record Length / (time/div * 10)

In above calculation, just make sure you do not cross your sampling rate provided by vendor. This calculation holds till 500ns/div, after that does some weird behaviour which I am still working on.